# Extracting data from online reports generated using mix of css and javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, curl

1. Please excuse me for the lengthy post.
2. Also, due to IP issues, I can share only very very limited snippet of the code (uses javascript, jQuery) of the tool (and developed by another group) that generates online reports mentioned below. !!!

As part of daily analysis into system stability, I have access to tons and tons of reports made available within company intranet. With some of these reports, I have used REST API and standard Python modules to extract the necessary data. There are these other "types" of reports which are generated using whole bunch of javascripts being executed in the background querying some kind of database (which is not exposed to end user and for which general access isn't provided too).

Am having trouble accessing the data from the latter reports i.e. those that use javascripts. Each and every output of the system report is viewable on a browser, it has got specific sections and to generate each of them couple of javascripts are used and then, all these are combined for the final overview provide report.

1. I have tried using *curl* (without any options) but the **output does NOT contain those mini tables which contain data about fail and pass rate** (this is generated using javascripts and jQuery statements).
2. I knew it wouldn't make any difference but still attempted to access the page using urllib2 module of Python ; however, this too did not yield what I really wanted.

jQuery code snippet:

```
jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
jQuery("a#tabs-a").each(function(){
var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');  //#tabs-1 (first a href inside tabs)
var id = href.replace("#", "");  //tabs-1
var file = id + ".html"; //tabs-1.html
var file_container = "div#"+id; //div#tabs-1
jQuery.get(file, function (data) {
jQuery(file_container+" div#content").html( jQuery("#hartsInfoTable").html() + data);
jQuery("table#detailsID").styleTable();
```

Final output is in the form of a mini table like:

```
ExecutionTime        TestCases      Pass      Fail   Blocked    NotExecuted
0:22:15              8               8         0     0          0
```

Want to know if anyone solved this kind of problem before ?

Comment: Could you just use javascript to scrape the page you need the data from? Something like  `$.get( "example.php", function(data) { // parse data ....});`

Comment: @DelightedD0D : Thanks for your response.                                                 I have **ZERO** knowledge in javascript. Am not asking for actual working code but any pointers to sample / examples would be of great help. Am willing to do multiple iterations to get to the working solution.